# Organizing and building properly mid-size PHP projects

Tags: php, model-view-controller, project

I wrote in PHP a learning management system for a small private school. It started a while ago when a lot of programming stuff was new to me. It is mostly scripts and includes based and doesn't contain classes or any MVC style organization, but it has grown big. What I am trying to do is to organize the current code without rewriting, so that it is good for fast iterations.

So far I changed it so that every role has its own folder/index/actions and all of them use one shared lib.php file to do sql queries and other related actions.

I talked to couple of MVC folks and considered PHPCake and Tonic as an option, but those seem to change dramatically what I already have. I am not sure if it just in my practice, but I just don't see how MVC will make it easier for me to develop faster. Can someone give tips or experience advise/opinions or maybe some helpful links. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC can be a useful framework for developing applications into logically separated components in a somewhat 'natural' way. It can increase your ability to develop quickly based mainly off the fact that some portions of the framework will end up being reusable and allow you to leverage that fact to develop new views and similar quickly. However, it is not necessary to use any particular framework or scheme to develop quickly as it can be done with a properly designed application of any nature.

An important thing to consider when developing an application in such a manner is code reuse. For example, making it simple to display pages with common layouts through a centralized mechanism, or having user-related functions placed into a user class/function set which can be reused site-wide instead of having individual functionality to handle it on each page.

In terms of modifying an existing application, I would focus on trying to centralize the components you are able to and making use of those components henceforth. This also makes modifying routines simpler because instead of potentially changing functionality on many areas of the codebase, you can change it in a single location and effect the application as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to make a pattern fit a problem is a very silly approach. Patterns are what code *is* not what what the code should be. In any object-oriented project presenting a user interface there will be instances of models, views and controllers - but there will also be lots of other patterns in the code - observers, decorators, iterators and more. They are useful learning constructs (e.g. "Here's how to implement a factory to build objects from relational data") and (human) language constructs (e.g. "That database connection class should be implemented as a singleton"). They are not design constructs.

> so that every role has its own folder/index/actions

Unless you've got a rather unusual definition of 'role', this architecture makes no sense. The most common criteria for dividing up high-level functionality are separation of concerns and grouping around common data sources.

You've mentioned frameworks - trying to adapt existing code to fit into a framework is usually a bad idea - it won't fit. They can be of benefit in structure your application and reducing the amount of effort if you sse them from the start of the project. Not from the middle / end.

Answer (score 0):

Put the new code you write under test. As the old code isn't, put it under test part-by-part as well. At the moment you've put everything under test, you should be fine for faster iterations.